# c++ compiler flags in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-options

I'm taking a MOOC course on data structures and algorithm. I would like to use c++, and I need to set my compiler options to the following

g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14  -lm

I'm currently using MS Visual Studio 2017 on Windows. Is it even possible? Do I need to do custom build? The following is the paragraph taken from  the MOOC mentions about Windows users having to use Cygwin, but I have no clue what that means. Can anybody shed some light on a feasible way to do this?

> Your solution will be compiled as follows. We recommend that when
>   testing your solution locally, you use the same compiler flags for
>   compiling. This will increase the chances that your program behaves in
>   the same way on your machine and on the testing machine (note that a
>   buggy program may behave differently when compiled by different
>   compilers, or even by the same compiler with different flags).
>
> C++ (g++ 5.2.1). File extensions: .cc, .cpp. Flags
>
> **g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14  -lm**
>
> If your C/C++ compiler does not recognize the "-std=c++14" flag, try
>   replacing it with "-std=c++11" or "-std=c++0x" flag or compiling
>   without this flag at all (all starter solutions can be compiled
>   without it). On Linux and MacOS, you probably have the required
>   compiler. On Windows, you may use your favorite compiler or install an
>   environment such as cygwin.

Comment: Those flags to gcc and you cannot use them with msvc.

Comment: `g++` is not the visual studio compiler. You will have to get it separately. [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) is one of the ways to install g++ on windows.

Comment: Since it says "On Windows, you may use your favorite compiler" you could declare msvc to be your favorite compiler, but expect to be accused of lying or having terrible taste.

Comment: You would need to read up on g++ compiler options, then read up on Visual Studio compiler options and try to find the equivalent options. That said, if they will build from source and run / test your code on a different platform and compiler, you really need to build it the same way before submitting to make sure you don't have any platform specific code that would cause problems.

Comment: @nwp Please refrain from pointless hate between different platforms.

Comment: You only need Cygwin or MinGW when you want to use GCC to build programs for Windows.  That does not sound like a problem you are having when you have access to VS2017.  Nothing special that you need to do if those are the recommended GCC options.

Comment: Something in these articles might help you:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/07/19/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/

Answer (score 0):

As they said you should choose cygwin (https://cygwin.com/install.html).

These would be the flags for msvc: `/std:c++14 /O2 /Im`

> You can set compiler options for each project in its Property Pages
>   dialog box. In the left pane, select Configuration Properties, C/C++
>   and then choose the compiler option category.
>   For the categories lookup: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category